# Prove that a power of odd number is always odd by induction.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction, parity

The problem has confused me for like half hour.

An integer is odd if it can be written as $d = 2m+1$. Use induction to prove that the ${d^n} = 1 \pmod2$

by induction, the basecase is pretty simple , let $n = 0$ then ${d^0}=1 \pmod2$ is correct. But I stucked in the I.H and inductive steps.

Any hints please?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just show that the product of two odd numbers is odd. If $d^{n-1}$ is odd, then $d^n=d*d^{n-1}$ is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you assume true up to an arbitrary integer $k$ (the Inductive Hypothesis), then prove true for the $k+1$ case.

So consider $d^{k} \equiv 1 \pmod 2$. So what happens when you multiply both sides by $d?$ You get $d^{k} * d \equiv d \pmod 2$. As $d$ is odd by the Inductive Hypothesis, we get that $d^{k+1}$ is also odd.

Alternatively, you can look at this combinatorially as well. So

$$(2m+1)^{k} = (2m+1)(2m+1)...(2m+1) = \prod_{i=1}^{k} (2m+1)$$

By expanding, the last digit will always be $1$. And every other term will be multiplied by $2m$, which implies that every other term is even. We know the even numbers are closed under addition, we have an integer of the form

$$2x + 1 = \sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{k}{i} (2m)^{i} * 1^{k-i}$$

Answer (score 2):

Your I.H. is that 
$d^n \equiv 1 \mod 2$. Then
$d^{n+1} = d^n(2m+1) = 2md^n + d^n \equiv d^n \mod 2 \equiv 1 \mod 2$ by the induction hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Specialize $\,S =$ odds $ $  in the following

**Theorem** $\ $ Let $\,S\,$ be a set of integers $ $  *closed under multiplication:* $\,n,m\in S\,\Rightarrow\, nm \in S.\,$
Suppose $\,a\in S.\,$ Then $\ a^n\in S\ $ for all integers $\,n\ge 1.\,$

**Proof** $\ $ By induction on $\,n.\,$ The base case $\,n=1\,$ is true by hypothesis: $\,a^1 = a\in S.\,$ If $\,a^n \in S\,$ then $\,a(a^n) = a^{n+1}\in S\,$ since $\,S\,$ is closed under multiplication, completing the induction.

Comment: Doubt: But then wouldn't we have to first prove that the odds are closed under multiplication? Or is that your point - to highlight the *essence* of the problem?

Comment: @Anant Yes, I presume known that $ $ odd $\cdot$ odd = odd. Yes, the point of the proof is to highlight that the result is a special case of an inductive extension of that: any set closed under a binary product is also closed under $n$-ary extensions of the product. Above is the special case when all arguments of the product are equal, i..e. the product is a power.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to just show that the product of a finite number of odd integers is odd. This can be done inductively if you like. Then your problem is a special case of this.

Base case: a single odd number is odd.

Inductive step: Assume $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_{k+1}$ are odd and that $p_k = (n_1)(n_2)\cdots(n_k)$ is odd. Then $n_{k+1}=2a+1$ and $p_k=2b+1$ for some integers $a,b$. Thus $p_{k+1}=p_kn_{k+1}=(2a+1)(2b+1)=4ab+2a+2b+1=2(2ab+a+b)+1$ is odd.

Hence the product of a finite number of odd integers is odd, and in particular $(2a+1)^k$ is odd for integral $a$ and positive integral $k$.

Comment: Note that there are subtleties here, e.g. the definition of such products requires knowledge of recursively defined functions, which is a more complicated and subtle use of induction than the OP.

Comment: @BillDubuque: I only introduced this shorthand for ease of reading. Is there really a problem? Is there any doubt that $n_{k+1}\prod_{i=1}^kn_i$ and $\prod_{i=1}^{k+1}n_i$ are exactly the same thing? Am I missing something?

Comment: Presumably the OP already knows about power functions, but may not (rigorously) know about general products. To rigorously define them requires knowledge of recursive definition of functions.